# "Cannot return null for non-nullable field" when subscribing on NestJS with Graphql

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, nestjs

I have a nodejs backend done with `Nestjs` and I'm using `Graphql`. My frontend is Ionic/Angular using Apollo-angular for graphql stuff. 
**I'm having a problem subscribing data additions / changes.** Playground (provided by Nestjs) works just fine, which gives me a hint that the problem is in frontend.

I have `game` and `scores` in my data model, each score belonging to a game. In frontend I'm trying to listen to the new scores added to a specific game.

#### Backend

Here's a snippet from my `resolver`:

```
@Mutation(returns => Score)
async addScore(@Args('data') data: ScoreInput): Promise<IScore> {
  return await this.scoresService.createScore(data);
}

@Subscription(returns => Score, {
  filter: (payload, variables) => payload.scoreAdded.game + '' === variables.gameId + '',
})
scoreAdded(@Args('gameId') gameId: string) {
  return this.pubSub.asyncIterator('scoreAdded');
}
```

Here's the `service` method:

```
async createScore(data: any): Promise<IScore> {
  const score = await this.scoreModel.create(data);
  this.pubSub.publish('scoreAdded', { scoreAdded: score });
}
```

These are in my schema.gql:

```
type Score {
  id: String
  game: String
  result: Int
}

type Subscription {
  scoreAdded(gameId: String!): Score!
}
```

#### Frontend

Based on `Apollo-angular`'s documentation, in my frontend I have this kind of service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'apollo-angular';
import { SCORE_ADDED } from './graphql.queries';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ScoreListenerService extends Subscription {
  document = SCORE_ADDED;
}
```

This is in the frontend's graphql.queries:

```
export const SCORE_ADDED = gql`
  subscription scoreAdded($gameId: String!) {
    scoreAdded(gameId: $gameId) {
      id
      game
      result
    }
  }
`;
```

and I'm using this service like this in my component:

```
this.scoreListener.subscribe({ gameId: this.gameId }).subscribe(({ data }) => {
  const score = data.scoreAdded;
  console.log(score);
});
```

#### The problem

With all this, my frontend gives me an error `ERROR Error: GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.scoreAdded.`

Doing the subscription like this in Playground works, no problem at all.

```
subscription {
  scoreAdded(gameId: "5d24ad2c4cf6d3151ad31e3d") {
    id
    game
    result
  }
}
```

#### Different problem

I noticed that if I use `resolve` in my backend's resolver like this:

```
  @Subscription(returns => Score, {
    resolve: value => value,
    filter: (payload, variables) => payload.scoreAdded.game + '' === variables.gameId + '',
  })
  scoreAdded(@Args('gameId') gameId: string) {
    return this.pubSub.asyncIterator('scoreAdded');
  }
```

the error in frontend goes away, BUT it screws up the data in subscription, playground getting the added score with null in each attribute and the subscribe in frontend is NOT triggered at all.

**Any help, what am I doing wrong here?**
It looks to me that my frontend is not correct but I'm not sure is it my bad or possibly a bug in Apollo-angular...

Comment: Is `score` defined inside the service method(i.e. does create actually return the created model)?

Comment: Yes, the service method returns the actual saved model correctly (in all of these cases). Without defining any `resolve` on backends Subscription part, everything works well on playground but the frontend Apollo client gets the `ERROR Error: GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.scoreAdded.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got my problem solved. As I suspected, the problem was in the frontend side code. So nothing wrong with the way I implemented the nestjs stuff on the backend side. Turned out to be a stupid mistake by me, not initializing the WS for subscriptions, which was clearly explained here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/subscriptions/.

So, I changed this

```
const graphqlUri = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({ graphqlUri }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: {
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    },
  };
}
```

to this

```
const graphqlUri = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';
const wsUrl = 'ws://localhost:3000/graphql';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  const link = split(
    // split based on operation type
    ({ query }) => {
      const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
      return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription';
    },
    new WebSocketLink({
      uri: wsUrl,
      options: {
        reconnect: true,
      },
    }),
    httpLink.create({
      uri: graphqlUri,
    })
  );
  return {
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: {
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: and from where do you import getMainDefinition ?

Comment: Found your question & answer straight away. I suspect you saved, at the least, my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Provided answer above is correct, but for those who want to see the packages version used and imported files check this solution:

**package.json** dependencies

```
{
   "dependencies": {
      "@apollo/client": "^3.2.5",
      "@apollo/link-ws": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
      "apollo-angular": "^2.0.4",
      "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18",
    }
}
```

**graphql.module.ts** code

```
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/link-ws';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { InMemoryCache, split } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';

const uri = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';
const wsUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';

export function createApollo(hLink: HttpLink) {
    
    const ws = new WebSocketLink({
       uri: wsUrl,
       options: {
           reconnect: true
       }
    });

    const http = hLink.create({uri});

    const newLink = split(
       ({ query }) => {
          const def = getMainDefinition(query);
          return def.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && def.operation === 'subscription';
       },
       ws,
       http
    );
    
    return {
        link: newLink,
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        defaultOptions: {
           watchQuery: {
              fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
              errorPolicy: 'all'
           }
        }
    };
}

@NgModule({
   providers: [
     {
        provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: createApollo,
        deps: [HttpLink],
     },
   ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```